# ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, match, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to write a regular expression to get the "url" from the following text:

```
[![title](thumbnail_url?height=240&width=320)](url)
```

using the following postgresql query:

```
SELECT (SELECT m[1] FROM regexp_matches(text, '^\[\!\[^*\]\(^ *\)\]\(((^*))') AS r(m) LIMIT 1) FROM texts;
```

I am getting the following error while I execute the above query:

```
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/mA2dK6/1), you try to repeat some functional regex elements that cannot be quantified. Try [`\[!\[[^\]]*\]\([^()]*\)\]\(([^()]*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/mA2dK6/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the final "url", then this expression would do the trick:

```
.+\)\]\((\S+)\)
```

Throw away everything up to and including the literal `)](`, then capture everything until the literal `)`.

```
SELECT regexp_matches(text, '.+\)\]\((\S+)\)')[1] AS m
FROM texts
LIMIT 1;
```